# Case expression in where in update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables CopyMoveSources and ListItems. CopyMoveSources has a column called TargetExists.

I need to set TargetExists to 1 or 0 dependant on whether the files exists in ListItems. And I must only check thise rows where TargetExists is null so I dont check the same files each time query is run. I would expect it to be some kind of case expression all input are appreciated.

```
select *
from [dbo].[CopyMoveSources] 
where source not in (select path from ListItems)
order by JobId asc
```

Comment: SQL Server has a `case expression` *not* a `case statement`.

Comment: OK. Would you use that or something else and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want an `update`:

```
update CopyMoveSources
    set targetexists = (case when exists (select 1 from listitems li where li.path = copymovesources.source)
                             then 1 else 0
                        end)
    where targetexists is null
```

Comment: Just tested this, it worked! Thanks alot highly appreciated!

Comment: How does this work: select 1 from listitems li where li.path = copymovesources.source)                             then 1 else 0? Is it like a select top 1 or is does it return 1 so exists suceeds?

Comment: @ThomasSegato . . . `exists` returns true when the subquery returns at least one row.  The values selected in the subquery are irrelevant.